# PHP shell_exec() returning different result than SSH Terminal

Tags: php, python-2.7, centos7, arduino-ide

I have a Linux machine running CentOS 7 with Python 2.7.5 installed. I am trying to run the Arduino-CLI, which is an executable that requires Python. I wrote a command to compile a sketch. As seen on the right side, it effectively compiles.

When I run the same command in PHP using sudo_exec(), it gives me:

```
Error during build: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
```

For context, I am logged in as the web-user on both the terminal and PHP. What could I do to fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The webuser when running the webserver does not run interactively and doesn't have user environment vars.  Use the full path `/path/to/python` or maybe look at `/etc/environment` or other files that may be more appropriate.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The arduino-cli runs python. My code doesn't directly refer to python. Is there anything I can do to run this properly in shell_exec() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out this problem. In `shell_exec()`, PHP does not define the PATH environmental variable. It also won't know the current working directory. So adding these couple lines before `shell_exec()` did the trick:

```
chdir("/home/gyropalm/subdomains/app/studio");  //set current working directory
putenv("PATH=/usr/bin/");   //required to define python path or Arduino-CLI complains
```